# Projecting a Climate Research Unit (CRU) CDF raster into a stereo polar view in R: how-to?

Tags: r, gis

How can a Climate Research Unit (CRU) CDF be projected into a polar view in R?

The package **cruts** and its function *cruts2raster()* gets the time-series data nicely and I can visualize one month's data (or more) using the **raster** package and the *plot()* or *image()* functions. After bringing in all the data and checking the RasterStack it plots and gives the coordinate reference system when queried but I can't get it to a polar projection.

I use **rgdal** (having installed the latest proj.4 into my Mac's /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig) but seem unable to project into this polar view:

```
library(cruts)
library(raster)
## Bring the downloaded file into R
r <- cruts2raster("cru_ts3.24.2011.2015.pre.dat.nc", 
                  timeRange=c("2011-01-01","2015-01-01"))
## get the first layer
r1 <- r[[1]]

## admire its colors (beautiful!)
plot(r1)

# check its coordinate reference system and projection
r1 
# gives this 
# coord. ref. : +init=epsg:4326 
# .             +proj=longlat 
# .             +datum=WGS84 
# .             +no_defs 
# .             +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

## define the stereo polar projection to make it really gorgeous
newproj <- "+proj=stere 
            +lat_0=90 
            +lat_ts=70 
             +lon_0=-45 +datum=WGS84"
## try to project
x <- projectRaster(r1,crs=newproj)
# and FAIL
```

"Error in if (value[1] != nrow(x) | value[2] != ncol(x)) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In `dim<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(nr, nc)) :
NAs introduced by coercion to integer range"

I have been unable to figure out the "missing values".

In the documentation for *projectRaster()* there's this: "projectExtent does not work very well when transforming projected circumpolar data to (e.g.) longitude/latitude. With such data you may need to adjust the returned object. E.g. do ymax(object) <- 90" but I don't know how to implement their advice.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes the problem for me:

r1e <- extent(-180,180,60,90)

r1c <- crop(r1,r1e)

plot(r1c)

x <- projectRaster(r1c,crs=newproj)

plot(x)